# How a domain automatically fetch website content from another server when first server is down?

Tags: server, dns

I have a domain and 2 servers. I put same website content in both servers. Suppose, if one server is down or hacked, the domain must show from second server. Can you help me with alternative options.

I heard on A records but not clear on that..or any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Loadbalancing for example Apache loadbalancer where you can configure this scenario.